# Hair on diffuse color pass is black and has no albedo information?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, materials, hair

I have a object (face with hair) and I want to get the *albedo* from my *diffuse color pass* in Blender 2.8. I only get the image without hair. How can I get the whole image or just its *albedo* color? I attached a simple example as well.

The code is:

def _prepare_albedo_node_graph(tree: bpy.types.NodeTree):
    if bpy.context.scene.render.engine != "CYCLES":
        raise RuntimeError("Depth GT (Radial Depth) is only supported with CYCLES renderer")

```
render_layers = tree.nodes["Render Layers"]
albedo_output_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
bpy.context.view_layer.use_pass_diffuse_color = True


albedo_output_file_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeOutputFile')
albedo_output_file_node.base_path = os.path.join(albedo_output_dir, "Albedo_c")
albedo_output_file_node.file_slots[0].path = "albc######"
tree.links.new(render_layers.outputs["DiffCol"], albedo_output_file_node.inputs["Image"])

return albedo_output_dir
```

[image]